# React-Native: Rotate and Animated Car with respective to heading

Tags: animation, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native-maps`, Right now i am able to update location of driver and update the `polyline`. What i want to achieve is like Uber, i want to animate the car to new coordinate and also rotate it with respective to the heading.
Right now i am able to update the polyline, but without animation, I did some research and i got to know that we use `Animated Markers` for this, but couldn't find a documentation for this implementation.
my render method:

```js
renderContent() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <Loading />
      );
    } else if (this.state.error) {
      return (
        <Card>
            <Heading> No directions available </Heading>
            <Button> 
              <Text> Retry </Text>
              <Icon name='refresh' />
            </Button>
        </Card>
      );
    } 
    if (this.props.liveLocation.origin !== null) {
      const { origin, des, coords } = this.props.liveLocation;
      return (
        <MapView
              provider='google'
              style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
              ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }}
              initialRegion={{
                latitude: Number(origin.lat),
                longitude: Number(origin.lng),
                longitudeDelta: 0.2,
                latitudeDelta: 0.2
              }}
              onLayout={this.onLayout}
        >
          {origin != null && <MapView.Marker 
            coordinate={{ latitude: Number(origin.lat), longitude: Number(origin.lng) }}
          >
            <Icon name='directions-car' />
          </MapView.Marker>}

           {des != null && <MapView.Marker 
            coordinate={{ latitude: Number(des.lat), longitude: Number(des.lng) }}
           >
             <Icon name='place' />
             </MapView.Marker>}

          {coords.length > 1 && 
                <MapView.Polyline
                            coordinates={coords}
                            strokeWidth={2}
                            strokeColor="black"
                />
                }
        </MapView>
      );
    }  
  }
```

origin has { lat, lng, heading, etc etc }

Comment: Hi @sarmad Aijaz Did you solve this and can you tell me how to achieve this

Comment: Hi, "Right now i am able to update the polyline" - maybe you could you describe how to update the polyline without getting new direction request? ...Just "locally on the map" remove a polyline part in accordance with new position? Thanks